# Android JPG images not opening in Photoshop

Tags: macos, android, image-editing, adobe-photoshop, adobe-lightroom

I have problems opening JPG files sent by Android smartphones. In Photoshop it says that i's impossibile to open the image since it lacks SOFn, DQT or DHT marker before JPEG SOS marker.

In Lightroom these images are grayed out as not readable.

With Preview I can open these images.

Why not with Adobe apps? Any indication to solve the problem easily?
Thanks !

Mac OS 10.14 / Photoshop CC

Answer (score 2):

I now understand that the problem lies in how Whatsapp saves JPG files, with a custom JPG format that is really a HEIC format.
If you change the extension from JPG to HEIC, even Photoshop will read the file.
I did a small Mac OS Automator app to change the file extension, that's useful if you have multiple "Whatsapp corrupted" JPG files.

Answer (score 0):

For me, opening with Preview and saving them with appropriate format allowed me to open in Photoshop. I cannot answer *why not with adobe apps.* Maybe the alert message says it all.

Go to File -> Export and select among JPEG or JPEG-2000, whichever solves the issue without much loss.

https://forums.adobe.com/message/10539823#10539823

https://helpx.adobe.com/in/photoshop/kb/error-invalid-jpeg-marker-displays.html

Answer (score 0):

I have created an open source tool for Windows and MacOS, to fix such broken WhatsApp jpeg files. You can check and download it here: https://github.com/cdefgah/whatsapp-jpeg-repair

Answer (score 0):

open in paint windows software save as ..it will open in photoshop or all

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer. Please keep in mind that this is an *Apple* centric site. Advising users “open a Windows application” isn’t likely to be useful or popular.  Perhaps an [edit] to your answer focusing on an Apple centric solution would be better?